Convergence of power method for dominant complex eigenvalue
Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonalisable matrix. Let the eigenvalues of $A$ are given by,
$$|\lambda_1 | = |\lambda_2| > |\lambda_3| \geqslant |\lambda_4|\geqslant \cdots\geqslant |\lambda_n|. $$
where $\lambda_1 = \overline{\lambda_2}$ are complex.
My question is, will the power method converge? In other words, is it possible to find the value of $|\lambda_1|$?

How would the real iteration converge to a complex eigenvalue or eigenvector? If you can solve that, then yes, the modified method will converge.

Actually I don't want the complex eigenvalue. I just need the modulus of it which is real. However, I tried to work out, but, it does not look possible to me. That is why I posted if the community knows an alternative result or so. The usual literature on power method assumes only one dominant eigenvalue which again implies that the dominant eigenvalue is real.

Essentially you need to do a subspace iteration for a 2-dimensional subspace. Then after the subspace has converged, take the restriction of the linear operator to this subspace and compute its determinant. For a complex-conjugate pair their product is their norm square is the determinant.
